# Bluetooth communication between an Android phone and a hardware device supporting bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'am trying to make an app that receives some binary data from a other device which is **not** running android. The Android phone should not transfer any data to this device. So over to my questions:

1. Should the phone act as the server which establishes the RCOMM channel?
2. Is it possible to connect the phone and this device without paring, as long as I know the MAC-address of the device? If so, how?

And yes, I have read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html so no need to only answer with that link. :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)
Phone should act as a **receiver**.

I found that the tricky part is to use *correct UUID*.

If you connect two phones you should be generating those and everything work fine, but on your hardware you can't change UUID that easily.
Take a look at these [reserved UUIDs](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.1_r1/android/bluetooth/BluetoothUuid.java#BluetoothUuid.0RESERVED_UUIDS).

For a Serial Port Profile's (SPP) communication use UUID `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`.

2)
You **can** connect to a device without pairing if you already know the MAC address, you don't even need to use BlueTooth discovery.

To get device using MAC address call [`getRemoteDevice(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getRemoteDevice%28java.lang.String%29)
and then [`createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29) to get `BlueToothSocket`.

Also take a look at [`checkBluetoothAddress(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#checkBluetoothAddress%28java.lang.String%29) to validate MAC address.